# mx:Text wrap inside of mx:List

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have a mx:Text tag with some text I would like to display in a list.  The code is below.

```
<mx:List id="projectList"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
                         dataProvider="{project.projectRequirements}"
                         borderThickness="0">
                    <mx:itemRenderer>
                        <mx:Component>
                            <mx:HBox height="100%"
                                     minHeight="20"
                                     paddingBottom="0"
                                     paddingLeft="0"
                                     paddingRight="0"
                                     paddingTop="0"
                                     width="100%"
                                     horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
                                     verticalScrollPolicy="off">
                                <mx:Text width="100%"
                                         fontSize="12"
                                         text="{data.requirement.requirementText}"/>
                            </mx:HBox>
                        </mx:Component>
                    </mx:itemRenderer>
                </mx:List>
```

If I manually set the height of the mx:HBox to something i know will allow for several lines, then the text will wrap. I was really hoping each component in the list could be a different height, determined by the amount of text.  Some of the text is 1 line, some is 4 or 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List has a variableRowHeight property that is set to false by default. Set it to true, then make sure your renderer does NOT have a height specified (so it is measured instead).

You don't need to wrap your component in an HBox, it can extend Text directly.